# How to get PowerShell to wait for Invoke-Item completion?

Tags: powershell, invoke, wait

How do I get PowerShell to wait until the Invoke-Item call has finished? I'm invoking a non-executable item, so I need to use Invoke-Item to open it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't by using the `Invoke-Item` Commandlet directly.  This command let has a void return type and no options that allow for a wait.

The best option available is to define your own function which wraps the `Process` API like so

```
function Invoke-Command() {
    param ( [string]$program = $(throw "Please specify a program" ),
            [string]$argumentString = "",
            [switch]$waitForExit )

    $psi = new-object "Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo"
    $psi.FileName = $program 
    $psi.Arguments = $argumentString
    $proc = [Diagnostics.Process]::Start($psi)
    if ( $waitForExit ) {
        $proc.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 27):

Just use `Start-Process -wait`, for example  `Start-Process -wait c:\image.jpg`. That should work in the same way as the one by @JaredPar.

Answer (score 21):

Pipe your command to Out-Null.

Comment: Can you provide an example? `Invoke-Expression ... | Out-Null`?

Comment: @TheMuffinMan ` myprogram.exe | Out-Null `  http://stackoverflow.com/a/7908022/217593

Answer (score 2):

### One easy way

```
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "xxxxx" -Name "mySession"
$Job = Invoke-Command -Session $session -FilePath "xxxxx" -AsJob
Wait-Job -Job $Job
```

Comment: don't forget to clean up `Remove-PSSession $session`