# Run an application with PowerShell and wait until it is finished

Tags: windows-7, powershell

Is it possible to run an application with `PowerShell` and wait until it is finished ?
For example I want to run `Thunderbird` and after user closes it, then print something to the output ?

Second thing - is it possible to search for this application using `thunderbird` keyword like in Start Menu (when we type it manually, it returns a result `Mozilla Thunderbird`) - and also run it ?

Thanks !

Comment: Something very similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1741490/465053)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
Start-Process myprogram.exe -NoNewWindow -Wait
```

Or if you would like a more concise mechanism, there's always the `Out-Null` hack:

```
myprogram.exe | Out-Null
```

Piping will wait for the program to terminate, and hence we pipe to `Out-Null`

As for finding an app, this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246768/finding-all-installed-applications-with-powershell) covers how to do this. Here is another article demonstrating [this method](http://myitforum.com/cs2/blogs/yli628/archive/2008/01/16/powershell-script-to-list-installed-software-on-local-computer.aspx).

You might also want to look at this article on how to make [Powershell interact with Windows Search](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/05/30/hey-scripting-guy-weekend-scripter-using-the-windows-search-index-to-find-specific-files.aspx) and [this one](http://www.dougfinke.com/blog/index.php/2008/12/21/powershell-querying-windows-desktop-search/), which is what the Start Button uses.

Comment: Works fine - and have you got any solution for finding application ?

Comment: @hsz, updated my answer with a pointer to a similar question someone asked and the solution. I don't know of any quick hack for this, but if I find one, I'll add it.

Comment: `Invoke-Expression "$($complete_command_with_args) | Out-Null"` worked for me.