# Editing WSL2 instance of Ubuntu Crontab using Windows VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

My question is whether it is possible to edit the crontab of a WSL2-based instance of Ubuntu with my Windows VSCode that is connected via WSL remote SSH.

If I type export `EDITOR=code` inside my WSL instance and then `crontab -e`, I am able to see a `/tmp/crontab.sygFAU` file load inside my VSCode instance.

The problem is that once I make edits to this file, it will save the file to `/tmp/crontab.sysFAU` but it doesn't actually take the next step of replacing the the real crontab file in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs`.

So once I re-open the crontab, it will just show what I had previously, and not my saved edits.

It would be nice to know if this is not possible or if there are any alternative ways to run a GUI editor because using nano is a pain!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Just a heads-up that this is *borderline* off-topic, but since you ask about VSCode (clearly a programming tool), I'm going to give it a pass (personally).  However, since you *also* are willing to accept *"any easy GUI alternatives"*, it could certainly be considered "non-programming".  Just for future reference, consider that questions like this *might* be a better fit for [Super User](https://superuser.com) or [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com) (both sister sites of Stack Overflow -- You can even use the same login you created here).  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An interesting question that I haven't considered before, myself.  Here's what's happening:

- You set your editor to `code`
- You `crontab -e`, which properly loads VSCode with the temporary crontab.
- However, because this is a Windows GUI application, it returns control to the parent Linux application (`crontab`) *immediately* after starting VSCode.  You can see the same result if you just start `notepad.exe` from your shell in WSL -- Once Notepad *starts* (rather than exits) control is returned to the shell.
- If you switch back to your terminal at this point, you'll see that `crontab` detected that the editor that it launched exited (returned), and so it has already tried to copy the temporary file to the permanent location.
- However, since the temporary files doesn't yet have any changes, `crontab` decides there's nothing to do.
- Editing the file in VSCode and saving it has no effect, other than to leave a dangling `/tmp/...` file hanging around (since `crontab` isn't there to clean up).

So what's the solution?  We need a way to launch a Windows GUI application and prevent it from returning control to `crontab` until you are done editing.

I originally thought something from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7908000/11810933) might work, but the problem is that the actual command that launches the Windows process is embedded in a shell script, which you can see with `less "$(which code)"` (or `code "$(which code)"`), but it's probably not a great idea to edit this.

So the next-best thing I came up with is a simple "wrapper" script around the (already-a-wrapper) `code` command.  Create `~/.local/bin/code_no_fork.sh` (could be anywhere) with:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
code $* > /dev/null
echo Press Spacebar to continue
read -r -s -d ' '
```

<sub><sup>Credit:</sup> [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/614939/432493) for the Spacebar approach</sub>

Then:

```bash
EDITOR=~/.local/bin/code_no_fork crontab -e
```

After you make your edits in VSCode, simply press <kbd>Space</kbd> to allow the script to continue/exit, at which point `crontab` will (assuming no errors were detected) install the new Crontab.

##### Alternatives

This is should *typically* only be a problem with Windows GUI applications, so the other possible avenue is to simply use any *Linux* editor that doesn't fork.  If you want a GUI editor, that's entirely possible as long as you are running a WSL release that includes WSLg support (now available for Windows 10 and 11).

I won't offer any individual editor suggestions since that would get into "opinion" and "software recommendation" territory, which is off-topic here.

Comment: Thank for for the explanation and workaround! I suspected it was a Windows thing.