# Using Powershell Invoke-Command on remote session to invoke executable by string

Tags: powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting, invoke-command

I want to write a Powershell script to invoke an executable on a remote machine by its path and then wait for it to finish running. This is what I've got so far:

```
$executable = "C:\Temp\example.exe"
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName VIRTUALMACHINE
$job = Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {$executable} -AsJob
Wait-Job -Job $job
```

Instead of running C:\Temp\example.exe, the remote machine runs the string $executable - not exactly what I was going for here!

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using some information from Bacon Bits' answer, information from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25218706/901812) answer, and some information from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2700939/901812) answer, I managed to piece together a solution.

```
$executable = "C:\Temp\example.exe"
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName VIRTUALMACHINE
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {Start-Process $using:executable -Wait}
```

The script block I was using before would run `$executable` as a script, that is return the value of `$executable` in the remote session, which just doesn't work at all. This doesn't get the local value of `$executable`, and it wouldn't run the executable anyway even if it did. To get the local value to the remote session, `$using:executable` will serve, but it still isn't being executed. Now, using `Start-Process $using:executable` will run the exeutable, as will `&$using:executable` or `Invoke-Expression $using:executable`, but it doesn't appear to work as the job will complete immediately. Using `Start-Process $using:executable -Wait` will achieve the originally intended task, although there are many ways to do this I think.

I will wait on accepting this as an answer until other people have had time to suggest perhaps better answers or correct any misinformation I may have given here.

Comment: Good research!  I'd completely forgotten about the variable scope issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need the call operator (`&`) to execute a string as though it were a script, or Invoke-Expression, or Start-Process.  Try `{&$executable}` or `{iex $executable}` or `{Start-Process $executable}`.

[Each one functions slightly different](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx), so you should definitely test them.  In my experience, you have to fiddle with them to get them to do what you want and behave the way you want.

Comment: None of these are working - it's always trying to execute what I give it literally instead of treating $executable like the variable it is. And besides, I can just call an executable from a Powershell session without & or Invoke-Expression or Start-Process and that seems to work.

Comment: If you can get it working and then show me some actual code that would be appreciated.