# Unable to Launch or Execute New Window or Applications on Remote System Using Windows PowerShell "Invoke-Command"

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-remoting, invoke-command, remote-execution

In Windows Powershell (admin):

## Connect to Remote Windows

`$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "xx.xx.xx.xx"`

## Attempting Remote Execution

```
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
            cd C:\Path
            ls
            Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Path\MyProgram.exe"
            start-Process cmd
        }
```

The cd and ls commands work as expected, but the Start-Process cmd and MyProgram.exe do not launch. No windows appear; it seems to be skipped.

I've also tried another approach:

```
PS C:\Jenkins> Enter-PSSession -Session $session
[xx.xx.xx.xx]: PS C:\Users\Administrator\Documents> Start-Process cmd
[xx.xx.xx.xx]: PS C:\Users\Administrator\Documents> (nothing happens)
```

Both way failed to launch or execute a new window or .exe file.

I tried to execute commands remotely and expected new windows or applications to be launched, but this did not happen.

Comment: I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31860641/using-powershell-invoke-command-on-remote-session-to-invoke-executable-by-string) , but still not work

Comment: It sounds like everything is working, and, assuming the file path is correct, I'm concerned about the fact that [Start-Process creates a new process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.3#description). Is there a reason you a cannot use [-NoNewWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.3#-nonewwindow)? And if you can use `-NoNewWindow`, what happens?

Comment: To explain further, I'm concerned that the current session has its own process, and any new process probably isn't part of the current session.  This is how things seem to work elsewhere, and may be what is happening here.

Comment: @Darin, it isn't creation of child processes per se that's the problem: any call to an external program requires one. While `-Wait -NoNewWindow` is a poor substitute for _direct_ invocation _locally_, in _remote_ invocations the `-NoNewWindow` causes the child process' output not to be shown - _direct_ invocation works in principle in remote session (synchronously, in the same window, with standard streams connected to PowerShell's streams), but running _interactive_ console applications (e.g. `cmd.exe` without `/C`)  is fundamentally unsupported.

Answer (score 2):

- Fundamentally - whether remotely or not - there's **rarely a good reason to use [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) to invoke *external programs***, especially if they're *console* applications.

  - **To *synchronously* invoke the latter *in the same window*, with their standard streams connected to PowerShell's streams**, *invoke them directly* (e.g. `&  "C:\Path\MyProgram.exe"`)
  - For guidance on when `Start-Process` is and isn't appropriate, see [GitHub docs issue #6239](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6239)
- In the context of PowerShell [remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Remote), there are additional pitfalls:

  - Given that `Start-Process` creates a *new window* by default, that window won't be visible in a remoting session.
  - Additionally, execution is *asynchronous*  by default (also in local calls).
  - While you could make the invocation *synchronous* with `-Wait`, an attempt to also run *in the same window* with `-NoNewWindow` does *not* work in remoting: you won't see any output (in local calls, you'll see the output, but you won't be able to *capture* it; that's why *direct* invocation is preferable).
- Finally, **PowerShell's remoting does *not* support *interactive* console applications**.

---

The **upshot** is:

- Assuming `"C:\Path\MyProgram.exe"` is a console application, use direct invocation in the remote session (`&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-), is needed for syntactic reasons, because your executable path is *quoted*):

  ```
  & "C:\Path\MyProgram.exe"
  ```
- However, your attempt to run `cmd` *without `/C` and a specific command*, i.e. your attempt to start an *interactive* session cannot work (the `cmd.exe` process starts up and quietly exits right away).

---

Options for **running *interactive* console applications remotely**:

- You can use **Windows Remote Management** via the built-in **[`winrs.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/winrs)** CLI, which supports interactive console applications. Windows Remote Management uses the same infrastructure (WSMan/WinRM) as PowerShell remoting, so chances are it will work for targeting computers where PowerShell remoting is enabled; see [the docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winrm/installation-and-configuration-for-windows-remote-management) for setup information.

  ```
  # Enter an interactive session on computer "yourcomputer"
  winrs -r:yourcomputer cmd
  ```

  - Note:

    - You could even start an interactive *PowerShell* session this way (`winrs -r:yourcomputer cmd`)
    - Whatever executable (plus arguments, if needed) you pass to `winrs.exe` is implicitly executed via (`cmd /c`).
- **Alternatively**, you can download and use **[`psexec`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec)**, which also supports interactive console applications, but uses a different remoting mechanism. It has many advanced features.